# Need image to jump to click location in Android

Tags: android

I'm writing a virtual joystick widget that consists of a large circle as the clickable area and a smaller circle representing the actual joystick.  To make manipulation a little easier, I want the user to be able to touch anywhere on the larger circle and the smaller circle will jump to the location of the touch.  If the user drags their finger I want the small circle to follow.  When the small circle is release I want it to jump back to its original position in the center of the large circle.  I'm using a Relative layout with both circles centered horizontally and vertically.

Here's the touch listener I'm using, right now it works mostly as I want, except the smaller circle appears up and to the left of where the touch is.  I can't figure out how to make it snap back to the center when released.

```
 OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            status.setText("X: " + event.getX() + ", Y: " + event.getY());
            knob.setX(event.getX());
            knob.setY(event.getY());
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these should be ImageViews. You should make a custom View and override the onDraw method. You can control drawing by overriding the onTouch method. It should look something like this:

```
public class Joystick extends View {
    float touchX = -1, touchY = -1;

    @Override
    public Joystick(Context context) {
         super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(myColor);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        float width = getMeasuredWidth();
        float height = getMeasuredHeight();
        canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, mPaint); //draw outer circle

        //Draw inner circle
        if (touchX > -1 && touchY > -1) {
            canvas.drawCircle(touchX, touchY, mPaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, mPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        switch (me.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touchX = me.getX();
            touchY = me.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchX = -1;
            touchY = -1;
        }
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: This is working fine for displaying the circles, however the inner circle is not moving when the screen is touched.  I went through the debugger and determined that the touches are in fact registering and retrieving valid x and y values.

Comment: Nevermind, it turns out I needed to add `invalidate()` after the switch so it would redraw the canvas.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to throw that in there. Good catch and good luck!